# How to choose node closest to all other nodes in a graph?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph, puzzle

Set of people need to meet. There exists a certain distance going from a person's house to the meetup house. The meetup house can be any person's house. What is the optimal house to choose as the meetup house? We are minimizing the total distance.

I thought of the naive solution where you go to each house and take the distance that each person has to travel to that location.

What would be the optimal solution for this problem?

Comment: What are you minimizing? Total distance? Or longest distance?

Comment: We are minimizing the total distance

Comment: What is the input to the problem, a weighted, fully connected, undirected graph?

Comment: yes that is the input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose the node with the lowest sum of incoming weights.

O(V^2) time complexity, where V is the number of nodes.

O(1) memory complexity.

Pseudocode:

```
min_dist = INF
min_node = null
for node in graph: // O(V) loops
    sum = 0
    for neighbor in neighbors(node): // O(V) loops
        sum += dist(node, neighbor)
        if min_dist <= sum:       // small optimization
            break
    if min_dist > sum:
        min_dist = sum
        min_node = node
return min_node
```

Comment: shouldn't it be would be O(V+E)

Comment: So the solution that I said was the naive solution is actually the optimal solution?

Comment: Take into account that the graph might not be fully connected, in which case you need to traverse the graph first and manage an O(V) table of distances for each node.

Comment: Computing the `sum of incoming weights` is an O(V) operation, so this is the naive O(V^2) solution. That said, I don't have a better answer.

Comment: It is actually `O(V ^ 3)` or `O(V * E * log N)`, because you need to find the shortest path to all nodes starting from each node. There are `O(V)` nodes and each search is `O(V ^ 2)` or `O(E * log V)`.

Comment: Why do you think that a shortest path from a node to another node always consists of exactly one edge?(Or do I misunderstand a problem?)

Comment: @user2040251 Because the [triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) holds when it comes to distance between the houses, so the direct (one edge) path is always the shortest.

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk Why does it hold true? It is not stated that Euclidian distance is used.

Comment: @user2040251 It's stated that set of people need to meet. Their houses are in the world where triangle inequality holds. If it is some other world, where it doesn't hold, then you're absolutely right.

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk Ok, it is more about the question quality, not your answer.